# Replacing one number with another in PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, string, character

I have declared a board array which is 10*10.I am reading the elements of the board which are 0, 1, and 2. After reading my board looks somewhat like this (shorter version 4*4)

```
   0  1  0  2 
   2  1  0  1 
   0  2  1  0 
   1  2  1  0
```

Code:

```
board = [] 
for i in xrange(0, 10) 
    board.append(raw_input())
```

now i want to change all occurences of 0 to 1. I am not able to change it..what should i do..please write the modified code..(getting error as immutable)

Thanks for the answer it got changed.I should first covert the list to string then use replace function

Comment: Please show us your code, how do you try to change it now. And what exact error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood, you have a list and just want to replace all 0's with 1's right? If it's like that, you can try to convert that list to string and use the `replace` method. Like: `board = str(board)` and then `board = board.replace('0','1')`. And then convert back to list with `eval` built-in function. But this may be too slow for big lists .

UPDATE >> If you do not want to use strings you can also code this:
If it is a 2d list like: `L = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0]]` then:

```
for x in L:
    for y in x:
        if y == 0:
            x[x.index(y)] = 1
```

And if it is just a common list like `L = [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1]` then:

```
for x in L:
    if x == 0:
        L[L.index(x)] = 1
```

Comment: OP will have to add some code, so we all know, but it looks more, like it is the other way around: Un"string"ify and work on real "states" a 2d array like mode of a game board.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in xrange(10):
    for j in xrange(10):
        if board[i][j] == 0:
            board[i][j] = 1
```

This should works. If not, please show me how you create your `board` table.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Its not working. I am taking inputs as a 10 line string in board.append(raw_input()). I dont want to change the input format and want to keep it as string itself even though the inputs are numbers